# Android Studio SeekBar Error

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm trying to get the value of a SeekBar in android studio. If i run app it is crashing. There is no syntax error.

```
package prosis.guiaturistico;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

private static SeekBar seek_bar;
private static TextView text_view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seekbar();
}

public void seekbar(){
    seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    text_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarValue);
    text_view.setText("Covered : " + seek_bar.getProgress() + " / " +seek_bar.getMax());

    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                int progress_value;
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    progress_value = progress;
                    text_view.setText("Covered : " + progress + " / " +seek_bar.getMax());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SeekBar in progress",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SeekBar in start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    text_view.setText("Covered : " + progress_value + " / " +seek_bar.getMax());

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SeekBar in stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is my layout.

```
<SeekBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/seekbar"
android:layout_above="@+id/bt_pes"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bt_mon"
android:max="5000" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:text="Small Text"
android:id="@+id/seekbarValue"
android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar"
android:layout_below="@+id/bt_caf"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bt_pes"    
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bt_pes" />
```

When I run I get these error messages and the emulator says that unfortunatly your program has stopped.

```
 04-27 16:26:18.615    2846-2846/prosis.guiaturistico E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: prosis.guiaturistico, PID: 2846
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prosis.guiaturistico/prosis.guiaturistico.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.SeekBar.getProgress()' on a null object reference
        at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at          
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at a   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.SeekBar.getProgress()' on a null object reference
        at prosis.guiaturistico.MainActivity.seekbar(MainActivity.java:27)
        at prosis.guiaturistico.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
at          android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
```

Comment: "This is my layout" - obviously, this is just part of your layout file. Can you post the whole. Also, **make sure** that your seekbar is defined in activity_main.xml layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
text_view.setText("Covered : " + seek_bar.getProgress() + " / " +seek_bar.getMax());
```

Both `seek_bar.getProgress()` and `seek_bar.getMax()` return primitive `int` values. The `TextView.setText()` method tends to assume primitive `int` values to be Resource IDs.

To avoid this, use `String.valueof()` to convert primitive values to a String representation. Or better yet, use a [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of plain String concatenation.

Comment: Even though seek_bar.getProgress() etc return int, as a whole, the argument to setText() above is converted to String anyway, exactly the same way as in eg. String s = "x=" + 10;, which evaluates to a string "x=10"; besides, "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.SeekBar.getProgress()' on a null object reference" indicates that the real issue is that seek_bar is null.

Comment: Yes at first glance it would seem so, but the error message is misleading. With the information OP gave, it's impossible for seek_bar to be null. And yes setText() should convert everything to a String, but in many cases it won't, which is why Android Studio projects by default throw an error in the editor when you do setText(10). The real issue here, is the use of plain String concatenation over a StringBuilder. Which is why my solution fixes OP's problem. So please, do some research before downvoting an answer. You might learn something new!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend... My program is working fine now :)